# How to configure FQDN in ovirt engine

Tags: fqdn, ovirt

I want to configure oVirt in Vultr bare metal server. But I don't know how to configure Engine VM FQDN. It always tell me `The address proposed for this host does not resolves locally`. There is error message:
[image]

And I've already configure my `/etc/hosts` file.
Here is my `/etc/hosts` code:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1 guest
::1       guest

127.0.0.1 VTest
::1       VTest
149.28.103.174 ovirt
127.0.0.2 test
```

I've tried FQDN `guest`,`localhost`,`ovirt`,`localhost.localdomain`. These all are not work. `149.28.103.174` is my public IP.

Comment: Your screenshot is taken from the oVirt engine setup process. Please provide such information in advance if you are asking questions on stackoverflow. I had to guess ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@smith cruise If you dont have you own DNS Servers you must enter in DNS entries in the /etc/host file on the oVirt node for the oVirt engine and oVirt node. Example

```
192.168.1.10  ovirt-engine-02.labl.local ovirt-engine-02
192.168.1.11  ovirt-node-02.labl.local ovirt-node-02
```

Credit to https://www.techbeatly.com/2020/03/installing-ovirt-4-with-self-hosted-engine-on-enterprise-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue myself. Eventually, I used a (sub) domain that was not pointing to my IP or entered in my Hosts and it that worked.

Comment: Could please to give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat RHEV documentation is saying:

> Red Hat strongly recommends using DNS instead of the /etc/hosts file for name resolution. Using a hosts file typically requires more work and has a greater chance for errors.

`ovirt` is not a [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). `engine.ovirt.yourdomain.com` is an example for a fully qualified domain name.

So the answer is: use DNS to define your hostnames of the oVirt components and provide the engine setup with a FQDN not just a hostname.

In case you can't use DNS, you can add the information to the /etc/hosts file on every oVirt node. It should contain the ip and name of the engine, all nodes and possible addional services. See the example.

```
# centos 7 localhost config
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

# engine and nodes
192.168.30.3    engine.infra.yourdomain.com
192.168.30.10   node01.infra.yourdomain.com
192.168.30.11   node02.infra.yourdomain.com
192.168.30.12   node03.infra.yourdomain.com
192.168.30.13   node04.infra.yourdomain.com
192.168.30.14   node05.infra.yourdomain.com
192.168.30.15   node06.infra.yourdomain.com

# additional services
192.168.30.9    cinder.infra.yourdomain.com
```

There are two sources of documentation. The [oVirt manuals](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/) are sometimes a bit sparse. The [Red Hat RHEV manuals](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_virtualization/4.3/) are much richer, although Red Hat biased.

Comment: Strong recomendation is not mandatory. Using /etc/hosts is not prohibited, so your answer is not relevant.

Comment: It is of course not forbidden to use etc/hosts. But it is recommended to use DNS. And for the strong recommendation: Thanks for the info, I will rephrase that. The documentation is just that important when learning oVirt. –