# Hostname of this host on the management network: Host name is not valid

Tags: dns, centos8, fqdn, ovirt

Note: This question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212221/how-to-configure-fqdn-in-ovirt-engine) (it dealt with the GUI/`cockpit` installation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009153/ovirt-fqdn-issue), however, those solutions did not work for me.

---

I have never ever used ovirt (this is my first time). I’d like to install it on a single physical server.

I have installed a CentOS 8 server, installed the required repo and packages (incl `cockpit`). Now I need to run `hosted-engine --deploy` to deploy the engine (I’d like to create the engine in a VM).

Everything seemed okay until the following showed up:

```
[ INFO  ] Stage: Setup validation
          Please provide the hostname of this host on the management network [host.domain.lan]:                                                
[ ERROR ] Host name is not valid: Host name host.domain.lan is not valid
```

`host.domain.lan` is FQDN hostname of the host (CentOS 8). As I understand it, neither IP nor non-DNS-resolvable hostname is not valid for ovirt.

I have never ever dealt with DNS (except for setting it up to `1.1.1.1` and `8.8.8.8`). I know that CentOS 8 uses `NetworkManager` by default, so I tried to add (using `nmcli`) a third DNS address, the address of the ovirt host (CentOS 8). `/etc/resolv.conf` indeed contained the address, but `hosted-engine` did not work.

Note that I have added two IPs with FQDNs into `/etc/hosts`, one for the host server (CentOS 8) and one for the ovirt engine (which should be deployed by the command and therefore the IP is not yet used). See below.

```sh
192.168.1.27 host.domain.lan
192.168.1.50 engine.domain.lan
```

I don’t want to use a private nor external/public DNS server.

Also note that when the program asked me if it should edit hosts file, I have answered `yes`.

How could I make `hosted-engine` work?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is my first response on Stack Overflow.

I have tried to reproduce the issue you are facing and I am pretty sure that the Host FQDN resolution is not working locally for you.

Reproducer Steps:

```
System Details & Networking:

# grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="oVirt Node 4.4.2" <- Latest Ovirt node

[root@rhvh ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search local
nameserver 192.168.122.1 

[root@rhvh ~]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.122.184 rhvh.local  rhvh
192.168.122.200 rhvm.local  rhvm
```

Snippet of 'hosted-engine --deploy' execution:

```
[1]
          --== HOST NETWORK CONFIGURATION ==--
          Please indicate the gateway IP address [192.168.122.1]: 


[2]
          Please indicate a nic to set ovirtmgmt bridge on: (ens1) [ens1]: 
          Please specify which way the network connectivity should be checked (ping, dns, tcp, none) [dns]: 
         


[3] 
How should the engine VM network be configured (DHCP, Static)[DHCP]? Static 
Please enter the IP address to be used for the engine VM []: 192.168.122.200

[ INFO  ] The engine VM will be configured to use 192.168.122.200/24
Please provide a comma-separated list (max 3) of IP addresses of domain name servers for the engine VM
Engine VM DNS (leave it empty to skip) [192.168.122.1]: 
Add lines for the appliance itself and for this host to /etc/hosts on the engine VM?
Note: ensuring that this host could resolve the engine VM hostname is still up to you
(Yes, No)[No] Yes


[4]
Please provide the hostname of this host on the management network [rhvh.local]: 
[WARNING] Failed to resolve rhvh.local using DNS, it can be resolved only locally
```

Could you try to set the DNS  as '192.168.1.1' in /etc/resolv.conf? Also, make sure you have answered the above 3 questions carefully which will contribute to correct FQDN resolution.

Comment: Thanks, @chetan8178! However, it did not work. Note that I try to install ovirt on one physical server with the engine as VM within ovirt and thus the engine does not exist yet. I presume that during deployment, ovirt validates/checks if the domain of engine exists, but it does not. Is that the problem?